# Method declared as final causes @EJB to be null, why?

Tags: nullpointerexception, ejb, wildfly, final, wildfly-10

I have the following method. When the method is declared `final` the `@EJB` is null. Why is this so? It works, when I omit the `final` keyword.

```
@Stateless
@TransactionManagement(TransactionManagementType.CONTAINER)
public class TokenService2
{
    @EJB
    private Configuration configuration;

    public final void processAuthentication(String authCode) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException
    {
        //here configuration is NULL.
    }
}
```

(The configuration itself is a singleton)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ejb beans do not like any other mehod modifier apart from `public` for business methods(methods invocable by clients).  Although this particular case looks like a bug in Wildfly. Wildfly 10 is JavaEE7 compliant, therefore its EJB container should conform the EJB 3.2 spec that says the following about session beans:

> Only public methods of the bean class and of any superclasses except
>   java.lang.Object may be  invoked through the no-interface view.
>   Attempted invocations of methods with any other access modifi- ers via
>   the no-interface view reference must result in the
>   javax.ejb.EJBException

So your business method cant be final anyhow, but your server should inform you about that.
.